# Avoid Broadcast nested loop join

Tags: apache-spark, join

When I join two dataframes using left join like this:

`df1.join(broadcast(df2), $"id" === $"id1" || $"id2" === $"id3", "left")`

Without `$"id2" === $"id3"`, it executes very quickly but when both conditions are present, it becomes `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin` and becomes very very slow.

Any ideas how I can improve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BroadcastNestedLoopJoin means nested for-loops to join your data-frames. It will always give a degraded performance.

Can you try below solution:

```scala
val resultPart1 = df1.join(broadcast(df2), $"id" === $"id1", "left")
val resultPart2 = df1.join(broadcast(df2),  $"id2" === $"id3", "left")

val resultDF = resultPart1.unionByName(resultPart2)
```

Union causes zero shufflings of data across executors.Hence produces faster results

Comment: What about records not matching in resultPart1 & resultPart2 ? You would end up with undesired records.